# Entity Framework - Problems to update user information

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

I'm new to Entity Framework, and I have to update a record in my database. I used the "Edit" example generated by the MVC3 framework and tried to customize to my needs.

I have a password field and before submit it to update I need to encrypt it with MD5. All process is running ok, except for the db.SaveChanges(); it saves the data posted by the form. Doesn't matter if I try to change the password, the framework just ignore that and save the data as it was posted in the form.

My .cshtml file:

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.Label("password", "Senha")
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.Password("password")
</div>
```

My method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Editar(FormCollection form)
{
    var newPassword = form["password"];
    var email = Session["email"].ToString();

    UserSet user = db.UserSet.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Email == email);

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //Changing password
        user.Password = Crypto.CalculateMD5Hash(newPassword);//this line is ignored
        TryUpdateModel(user);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return Redirect("~/Home/Mural");
    }
     return View(user);
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your line

```
TryUpdateModel(user);
```

Will overwrite anything you've done on your model prior.

Change the order to

```
TryUpdateModel(user);
user.Password = Crypto.CalculateMD5Hash(newPassword);//this line is ignored
```

And it'll probably work.

Comment: Thank you toxaq, I'l never realize by myself, even because it seems illogical at the first sight.

Comment: No worries. I find when I get stuck on something I think should be simple that [Teddy Bear Pair Programming](http://asimjalis.blogspot.com/2004/07/pair-programming-with-teddy-bear.html) helps